# Text in TextView sometimes is shown vertical. How to prevent it?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I have this layout:

```
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              android:id="@+id/layoutUsers"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="left"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        >
                </LinearLayout>
```

I add a few textviews into "layoutUsers" layout  programmatically:

```
    TextView textView1=new TextView(this);
    textView1.setText("some text");
    layoutUsers.addView(textView1);
```

And I have the following performance:

[image]

How to prevent text from being vertical?
How to show all text in a few lines?
Every text has own color, so I can't combine all textviews into one.
I guess we should do something with layout, not with textviews inside it...

Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Comment: set `android:lines="2"` or use `android:maxLines="2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a few textViews in layout, because they had different color and font.
I've discovered that I can use only one textView with HTML text.
Like this

```
    String SPACE="nbsp;"
    info+=SPACE+"user=<B><FONT color=#666666> someName+</FONT></B>";
    textInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(info));
```

Answer (score 0):

`setLayout Params` for `TextView` programatically

Comment: Which params? There are a few textViews.

Comment: I added both android:lines="2" and android:maxLines="2" for all textViews. It does not help. I will update my post above with full layout now